# JavaScript parse int from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have string: "You can vote 36 times for topics and 84 times for comments".

I need to get number 84 from string (number can be different).

How can I do it?

Comment: Doesn't need to try if knows nothing about regex

Comment: Ah there is good number of `what-have-you-tried`-Guys here, noobs and beginners, no luck for you guys. Say thanks to @qwertymk who is NOT `what-have-you-tried`-Guy like me :)

Comment: @Blaster: Asking does not hurt anyone. Even an answer such as "I don't have any idea how to approach this" might give some idea about the level of knowledge.

Comment: There are [many related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+extract+number+from+string) btw.

Comment: @FelixKling: I hate those words, three people passed by without answering just by seeing your comment and upvoting them meaning 4 people who stumbled upon this question. Im my opinon, that philosophy does not suit for this question at least.

Comment: @Blaster: When I commented, qwertymk already provided is answer, so that's more likely to be the reason that one else answered. It's a  reminder to include any related research effort. Granted, this question did not necessarily need it, but I rather comment one time too often than not enough.

Comment: @Blaster I think it's common courtesy to show that you've put in effort to answer your own question before coming here and asking for the answer, and that there's nothing wrong with encouraging people to ask full, proper questions at all times. Providing more information than is perhaps necessary is better than providing less, and even saying "I don't even know where to begin, so can't look for the information on my own" at least indicates you've thought about doing something other than asking here straight away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^You can vote \d\d times for topics and (\d\d) times for comments$/.exec(str);
```

Or:

```
/^You can vote \d+ times for topics and (\d+) times for comments$/.exec(str);
```

Comment: @tucnak then click the arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

OR try this lil different: **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/GyK7J/

**code**

```
var s = "You can vote 36 times for topics and 84 times for comments".;
var firstnumber = parseInt(/vote\s(\d+)/.exec(s)[1], 10);
var second = /and\s([\d+]+)/.exec(s)[1];
```